# Get xpath for nodes that form a string in HTML document

Tags: python, html, regex, xml, xpath

Problem: I want to find the xpath of node(s) that form a text string in an HTML document. Language used is python (lxml to parse the document)

To illustrate the idea consider the document:

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>sample document</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">
  <HR>
  <a href="http://google.com">Goog</a>
  <H1>This is one header</H1>
  <H2>This is a another Header</H2>
  <P>Travel from
    <P>
      <B>SFO to JFK</B>
      <BR>
      <B><I>on May 2, 2015 at 2:00 pm. For details go to confirm.com </I></B>
      <HR>
      <div style="color:#0000FF">
        <h3>Traveler <b> name </b> is
        <p> John Doe </p>
      </div>
.....
```

Now, given the strings "SFO to JFK on May 2, 2015" and "Traveler name is John Doe", how can I get the Xpath for the first node in the set of nodes that form the string. (if that is difficult even the set of nodes will do)

Sample outputs:

```
"SFO to JFK on May 2, 2015" -> /html/body/p/p/b
"Traveler name is John Doe" -> /html/body/p/p/div/h3
```

As a followup, instead of the strings above, if we have a regex, what would be the approach to solve the problem?

**Note**: In terms of python implementation, I was approaching the problem as in the snippet below

```
import lxml.html as lh
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

elem_tree = lh.parse(StringIO(html_document))
xpath = etree.XPath(_the_xpath_here)
list_of_nodes = xpath(elem_tree)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the xpath be just "//B" because that is the only html element you are searching for that should give you an array of all B elements on the page. Also you can run xpaths in chrome console using $x("xpath");

Comment: Well, sorry I should have clarified. The document is not fixed. As in the question should be if I have any HTML and a set of strings, how would I get the xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach :

```
import lxml.html as lh
from lxml import etree

elem_tree = lh.parse("Q12.html")
input_string = ["SFO to JFK on May 2, 2015", "Traveler name is John Doe"]

for i in input_string:
    xpath = "//*[contains(normalize-space(.), '{0}') and not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(.), '{0}')])]/*"
    node = elem_tree.xpath(xpath.format(i))[0]

    print '{0} -> {1}'.format(i, elem_tree.getpath(node))

    #Output:
    #SFO to JFK on May 2, 2015 -> /html/body/p[2]/b[1]
    #Traveler name is John Doe -> /html/body/div/h3
```

Brief explanation :

- `contains(normalize-space(.), '{0}')` : filter nodes containing *the text* (one of the `input_string`)
- `not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(.), '{0}')])` : select the node if any of it's descendant doesn't contain *the text*. In other words, select the inner most node containing *the text*.
- [`getpath()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getpath) : "*returns a structural, absolute XPath expression to find the element.*"

**UPDATE :**

Replace trailing `/*` in `xpath` variable string to this :

```
/descendant-or-self::*[contains('{0}', text()) or contains(text(), '{0}')]
```

Worked for HTML structure posted in question as well as the one you linked in below comment. However, addressing general cases having different characteristic of what has been demonstrated by both sample HTML is beyond the scope of xpath query in this answer.

Comment: Good answer and explanation, except it did not work for all the strings for me. (Eg html at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3d4b059464773ebd2d2f and the string I was trying to find the path for was 'Phone: 1-213-484-7000' but the 'xpath'  above failed to find any node for the same).

Comment: @Ark Check **UPDATE** section, that would work for HTML in the gist you linked too. However, I'm not trying to solve the entire requirement you put in question. Seems too much :p

Comment: Thanks for the update! Yeah, the generic solution would be difficult as there might be subtle cases. However I think your answer gives a good start point. :)